# CSS Transition Transform: Sliding element one way, and having it slide back in from the opposite direction

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate, transform, transition

I'm wanting to animate the slide of `span` to the left, than when transition stops, have it instantly move to another position without transition, and then afterwards slide it back into it's original position with transition. I must use CSS for the animation, not JS.

My problem is once I've animated the span to the left, and had it instantly go move, I cannot transition back into position.

Here's an example (click the span to animate): http://jsbin.com/tosaxedura/3/edit

```
body, html, div {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    background:black;
    display:block;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
span {
    display:block;
    height:inherit;
    width:inherit;
    background:red;
    transition:transform 275ms cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 0.745, 0.715), opacity 275ms cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 0.745, 0.715);
}

$('body').on('click', 'span', function () {

    var self = $(this);

    self.css('transform', 'translateX(-100%)').css('opacity', '0.5');

    self.one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', function (e) {

        self.css({
            'transition-duration': '0',
                'transform': 'translateX(100%)'
        });



        // move back into original position (overlaying the black) with animation   
        self.one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', function (e) {

            //self.css('transition-duration', '');
            //self.removeAttr('style');

        });

    });

});
```

Comment: _" I must use CSS for the animation, not JS"_ so why did you used script tags in the question? More than that, you should create those animations in the CSS and just apply/remove the class instead of write it entirely in the element.

Comment: For the animation: That is a CSS transition and not .animation(). JS tag because I'll have to use transitionend - no such functionality in CSS yet.

Comment: Han, so now I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you were trying to accomplish:

http://jsbin.com/tayupizepe/1/watch?html,css,output

This slides the element to the left, hides it, moves it all the way to the right *while hidden* (that's the key), reveals it, and slides it back to the starting position.

Comment: great no-js solution. @arber please include a brief explanation of what you did

Comment: Thanks for the edit @henry, I'm at work so was trying to be quick.

Comment: Adding "-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;" to the span will prevent a 1px jit in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/cihurigoba/3/edit

CSS:

```
body, html, div {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body, html {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

div {
    background:black;
    display:block;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
span {
    display:block;
    height:inherit;
    width:inherit;
    background:red;

   transition: transform 200ms cubic-bezier(0.470, 0.000, 0.745, 0.715);
}



.left.slideOut {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  opacity:0.5;
}

.left.instant {
 transform: translateX(100%);
 transition: none;
}

.left.slideIn {
    opacity:1;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.right.slideOut {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  opacity:0.5;
}

.right.instant {
 transform: translateX(-100%);
 transition: none;
}

.right.slideIn {
    opacity:1;
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <span class="left"></span>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
var clickspam = false;
$('body').on("click", "span", function () {

    if (!clickspam) {
        clickspam = true;
        shift($(this));
    }

});

function shift(self) {

    if (!clickspam) return false; clickspam = false;

    self.addClass('slideOut');  
    $('.slideOut').one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', function (e) {

      self.removeClass('slideOut').addClass('instant');

      setTimeout(function () {

        self.removeClass('instant').addClass('slideIn');


          //self.removeClass('slideIn');


        }, 1);

    });


    // unlock clickspam
    setTimeout(function () {
        clickspam = false;
        $('span').removeClass('slideIn instant slideOut');

    }, 500);

}
```